# Copy file field

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to copy a file field from a node to another node when I google how to do so I found this solution

```
$fid=9;//fid of the file
$file = file_load($fid);
$node->field_pro_thumbnail[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array($file);
node_save($node);
```

however I get the following error

> `PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'fid' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {file_usage} (fid, module, type, id, count) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => file [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 51 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 ) in file_usage_add() (line 692 of C:\xampp\htdocs\someueue\includes\file.inc)."`

Any Help please??

Answer (score -1):

maybe something like:

```
$node->field_pro_thumbnail[LANGUAGE_NONE][$fid] = array($file);
```

Comment: this is avoid the mentioned error however I get the following
Warning: Illegal offset type in util_node_presave() (line 93 of C:\xampp\htdocs\someueue\absher\sites\all\modules\util\util.module).
util is the name of my custom module